# DRYing up similar code in controller methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dry

I've got two methods in a controller with very similar code. Wondering how I could DRY them up! They both utilize [csv-importer](https://github.com/pcreux/csv-importer) gem to parse a csv file.

sales_controller.rb

```
  def import_csv_test
    user_id = params[:user_id]
    import = ImportSaleCSV.new(file: params[:file]) do
      after_build do |sale|
        sale.user_id = user_id
        skip! if sale.email == nil
        skip! if sale.order_date == nil
        skip! if sale.amount == nil
      end
    end
    import.run!
    redirect_to lifecycle_grid_sales_path, notice: import.report.message
  end

  def import_ftp
    user_id = params[:user_id]
    import = ImportSaleCSV.new(path: './public/uploads/gotcha.csv') do
      after_build do |sale|
        sale.user_id = user_id
        skip! if sale.email == nil
        skip! if sale.order_date == nil
        skip! if sale.amount == nil
      end
    end
    import.run!
    redirect_to lifecycle_grid_sales_path, notice: import.report.message
  end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may refactor both your methods into single one:

```
def import(hash)
  user_id = params[:user_id]
  import = ImportSaleCSV.new(hash) do
    after_build do |sale|
      sale.user_id = user_id
      skip! if sale.email == nil
      skip! if sale.order_date == nil
      skip! if sale.amount == nil
    end
  end
  import.run!
  redirect_to lifecycle_grid_sales_path, notice: import.report.message
end
```

And then call it:

```
import({file: params[:file]})
import({path: './public/uploads/gotcha.csv'})
```

It doesn't seem that method belongs to your controller so you may want to extract it somewhere. I encourage you to check [this great article](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/) and extract your method into brand new Service object.

Comment: Yep, that appears to be the only difference.

Comment: This looks great, thank you!
Would I define the import method directly in my sales_controller.rb?

And call it like this?
`def import_csv_test

  import({file: params[:file]})

end
`

Comment: Yeah, you can do that. It doesn't seem that method should live in your controller. So you probably need to extract it somewhere else. The great choice would be Service Class with the single public method `call` (exactly the same as `import` method) and several private methods if needed. So in your controller you'll be able to create the instance of that Service and call `call` method on it. I'll edit my answer with some useful link for you.

Comment: Thanks again, appreciate your help. I'll check it out once I wake up.
Nice profile haha...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can extract a class to do the heavy lifting.

```
class ImportSaleCSVCreator
  def initialize(csv_options = {}, csv_attributes = {})
    @csv_options = csv_options
    @csv_attributes = csv_attributes
  end

  def build
    ImportSaleCSV.new(csv_options) do
      after_build do |sale|
        csv_attributes.each { |k, v| sale.public_send("#{k}=", v) }
        skip! if sale.email.nil? || sale.order_date.nil? || sale.amount.nil?
      end
    end
  end

  private

  attr_reader :csv_options, :csv_attributes
end

class Controller
  def import_csv
    import = ImportSaleCSVCreator.new({ file: params[:file] }, { user_id: params[:user_id] })
    import.run!
  end

  def import_ftp
    import = ImportSaleCSVCreator.new({ path: './gotcha.csv' }, { user_id: params[:user_id] })
    import.run!
  end
end
```

Make sure you check attributes passed. Especially when dealing with files, paths, etc. You might want to filter the parameters in `ImportSaleCSVCreator`.